# Make scrollpane always on top

Tags: java, javafx, scrollpane

So, in my program, at the bottom, I've got a `ScrollPane` which has a `TextFlow` inside it to display a information in when the user clicks on items in a list. The `ScrollPane` was rather small, so I added an expand button which makes it larger so you can see more. But now, if there is a button or anything within the area that the expanded `ScrollPane` takes up, it is always on top of the pane and makes it hard to see anything. Is there a way I could force the `ScrollPane` to be on top and cover things? Attempting to change the z-index did nothing.

Should I just set anything within that area to be not visible while expanded instead?

This is what I'm doing to expand the `ScrollPane`:

```
        Image expand_img = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("expand.png"));
    Button expand = new Button();
    expand.setGraphic(new ImageView(expand_img));
    expand.setLayoutX(630);
    expand.setLayoutY(415);
    expand.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent");
    expand.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            ++clicked;
            if (clicked % 2 == 0){
                scroll_desc.setTranslateY(-100);
                scroll_desc.setPrefHeight(208);
                expand.setLayoutY(315);
            }else if (clicked % 2 == 1){
                scroll_desc.setTranslateY(0);
                scroll_desc.setPrefHeight(108);
                expand.setLayoutY(415);
            }
        }
    });
```

I just want it so that when the `ScrollPane` is larger, anything inside the new area is covered up by the `ScrollPane` rather than being overlayed on top and accessible, thus obscuring content of the descriptions and the like displayed.

Comment: Please share more code so others can help you. Refer to [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: what kind of container is the scrollpane in? It doesn't much matter that there's a `TextFlow` inside it, but the *parent node* of the `ScrollPane` & other buttons and stuff is what manages their layout.

Comment: The `ScrollPane` actually isn't in anything. It didn't seem necessary at the time, though that's easily fixed.